# sprintf not working when format contains non-ASCII characters

Tags: c++, gcc, android-ndk, printf, clang

The following call to `sprintf` fails when compiled for i386 arch. using the Android NDK. I have tried compiling with both GCC and clang, and the result is the same. I'm using `android-ndk-r10e` (with APP_STL set to `gnustl_shared` with GCC, `c++_shared` with clang). It works as (*I?*) intended when compiling for ARM with the same configuration, and furthermore when I'm compiling for i386 Linux with GCC 5.2.

```
int n = sprintf(buf, "\xc0%s", "test"); // n == 0, strlen(buf) == 0
```

After the call, `buf` is empty rather than containing the expected char sequence "\xc0test". `sprintf` appears to ignore everything after the first non-ASCII character. The following code writes "test" to `buf`, leaving out the last byte:

```
sprintf(buf, "%s\xc0", "test"); // strlen(buf) == 4
```

On the other hand, this works fine:

```
sprintf(buf, "%s", "test\xc0"); // strlen(buf) == 5
```

I'm perplexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known Android problem. The problem resides in Android libc implementation (Bionic), which is fairly incomplete in terms of conforming to standards. In particular, Bionic stdio implementation doesn't support non-ASCII characters properly.

This simple test prints `strlen(buf)=4` when being built by Android NDK r10e:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[256];
    sprintf(buf, "%s\xc0", "test");
    printf("strlen(buf)=%d\n", strlen(buf));
    return 0;
}
```

Solution: use [CrystaX NDK](https://www.crystax.net/android/ndk) - alternative fork of the Google's Android NDK, where that problems were fixed. The example above works properly if being built by the CrystaX NDK 10.3.1:

```
strlen(buf)=5
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I see you are the creator of CrystaX, so thank you very much for that. `stdlib.h` didn't contain `labs`, but that was trivial to fix.

Comment: Hmm, actually `stdlib.h` contains `labs` definition. If you experience problems with that, please feel free to file a bug with a minimal reproducible case on our issue tracker - https://tracker.crystax.net/projects/ndk.